# Parse JSON from html tag using Python

Tags: python, regex, json, python-2.7

I've used BeautifulSoup to get the below snippet from an HTML page.  I'm having trouble stripping out just the JSON (after FB_DATA).  I'm guessing I need to use re.search, but I'm having trouble with the REGEX.

The snippet is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var FB_DATA = {
        "foo": bar,
        "two": {
          "foo": bar,
        }};
    var FB_PUSH = []; 
    var FB_PULL = []; 
</script>
```

Comment: What do you have for a regex so far?

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know where to start.  I hate posting with so little to go on, but i'm just learning and i'm not strong with regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming your main issue is using a `.*?` when `.` matches anything but new lines.  Using the `s` dot-matches-newline modifier, you can accomplish this very simply:

```
(?s)    (?# dot-match-all modifier)
var     (?# match var literally)
\s+     (?# match 1+ whitespace)
FB_DATA (?# match FB_DATA literally)
\s*     (?# match 0+ whitespace)
=       (?# match = literally)
\s*     (?# match 0+ whitespace)
(       (?# start capture group)
 \{     (?# match { literally)
 .*?    (?# lazily match 0+ characters)
 \}     (?# match } literally)
)       (?# end capture group)
;       (?# match ; literally)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tU3zX8)

---

Your JSON string will be in capture group #1.

```
m = re.search(r"(?s)var\s+FB_DATA\s*=\s*(\{.*?\});", html)
print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

start with

```
FB_DATA = (\{[^;]*;)
```

and see in which cases it's not enough.